# c++ primer plus chapter 2 ex7 - cant solve it

Tags: c++

i am try to solve ex7 from chapter 2 (Prata's c++ primer plus)

The task is:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter an hour value and a minute value.The
>   main() function should then pass these two values to a type void function that displays
>   the two values in the format shown in the following sample run:
>   Enter the number of hours: 9
>   Enter the number of minutes: 28
>   Time: 9:28

My Code is :

```
#include <iostream>


void hours(int);
void minutes(int);


int main()

{
    using namespace std;
    int hhrs;
    int mnts;
    cout << "Enter hours: "; cin >> hhrs; cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter minutes: "; cin >> mnts; cout << endl;

    hours(hhrs);
    minutes(mnts);

    cout << "Time is: " << hours << ":" << minutes << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void hours(int n)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << n;
}

void miutes(int m)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << m;
}
```

Errors are :

1) Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl minutes(int)" (?minutes@@YAXH@Z) referenced in function _main   G:\~DEV#c++\he\he\Source.obj

2) Error    2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   G:\~DEV#c++\he\Debug\he.exe    1

Comment: You spelled `miutes` wrong

Comment: instead of `using namespace std;` in every scope, you can put it at the begin of the program. But [it's a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714) and you should use `using std::cout` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your misspelling (`miutes` instead of `minutes`), you also are not doing what the problem is asking:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter an hour value and a minute
>   value.The main() function should then pass these two values to a type
>   void function that displays the two values in the format shown in the
>   following sample run: Enter the number of hours: 9 Enter the number of
>   minutes: 28 Time: 9:28

That is asking you to input 2 values, and pass those values to a *single* function that will print them in the desired format.

Comment: I was just about to say that. Have a plus.

Comment: Thank you! One more question , why is it printing like this ? - http://puu.sh/5SYXi.jpg  I mean "210" before "time"

Comment: You would have to show your updated code in order to answer that.

Comment: @user3050045 You are printing the values twice:  `cout << n; cout << m; cout << "Time is: " << n << ":" << m << endl;` should be just `cout << "Time is:  " << n << ":" << m << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

You misspelt `minutes` in the function definition.

```
void miutes(int m)
     ^^^^^^
```

Note that your `hours` and `minutes` functions do exactly the same thing. There's no point having both of them. You could have a single function called `print`. However, since all they do is call another single function (`cout.operator<<`), I would just get rid of them all together. Just do `cout << hhrs` and `cout << mnts` when you need it. Your problem does require you to move the printing of *both* the hours and minutes into a function though.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the spelling mistake in `void miutes(int m)`, the logic does not require two seperate functions to call.

Also if you check the below line:

> cout << "Time is: " << hours << ":" << minutes << endl;

Here "hours" and "minutes" will always evaluate as `True`. So eventually it will show 1:1 in output, not 9:28 (as per your input).